# How to make a group voice call in Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

How to make a group call to my group (Google Hangouts Voice Chat)?
Tell me please.
I am not able to find this information in the API documentation.

I want to automate the call.
What would the script worked every day and gathered people for a group meeting.